# Retrieve image from drawable and String convert to Int issue

Tags: android, android-imageview, parseint

i am currently doing a page which retrieve data from php server and now trying to retrieve and image from drawable by using setImageResource but is not working, i dunno what wrong with it and is it possible for me to just save image name in database then retrieve image by using image name?
beside that, i try to do a simple plus minus button for quantity but the apps force stop once i click on the button..

```
public class FoodDetailActivity extends Activity 
{
TextView FoodName;
TextView FoodDesc;
TextView FoodPrice;
ImageView FoodImg;
EditText Number;
Button plus;
Button minus;
Button Addcart;

String fid;
int number;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

// single product url
private static final String url_food_details = "http://10.0.2.2/android_user/FoodDetail.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_FOOD = "food";
private static final String TAG_FID = "fid";
private static final String TAG_FOODNAME = "food_name";
private static final String TAG_FOODPRICE = "food_price";
private static final String TAG_FOODDESCRIPTION = "food_description";
private static final String TAG_FOODURL = "food_url";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_detail);


    // button
    plus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_plus);
    plus.setOnClickListener(increase);
    minus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_minus);
    minus.setOnClickListener(decrease);
    Addcart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
    Number = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text_number);

    // getting food details from intent
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // getting food id (fid) from intent
    fid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_FID);

    // Getting complete product details in background thread
    new GetFoodDetails().execute();
}

// Increase number of quantity
    private OnClickListener increase = new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            String quantity = Number.getText().toString().trim();
            number = Integer.parseInt(quantity);
            if(number > 0 && number < 99)
            {
                number = number + 1;
                Number.setText(Integer.toString(number));
            }
            else if(number == 99)
            {
                number = 1;
                Number.setText(Integer.toString(number));
            }
        }
    };
 // Decrease number of quantity
    private OnClickListener decrease = new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            String quantity = Number.getText().toString();
            number = Integer.valueOf(quantity);
            if(number > 1 && number <= 99)
            {
                number = number - 1;
                Number.setText(Integer.toString(number));
            }
            else if(number == 1)
            {
                number = 99;
                Number.setText(Integer.toString(number));
            }
        }
    };

class GetFoodDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> 
{
    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(FoodDetailActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading food details. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Getting product details in background thread
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
    {

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                // Check for success tag
                int success;
                try {
                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fid", fid));

                    // getting product details by making HTTP request
                    // Note that product details url will use GET request
                    JSONObject json = JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(url_food_details, "GET", params);

                    // check your log for json response
                    Log.d("Single Food Details", json.toString());

                    // json success tag
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                    if (success == 1) 
                    {
                        // successfully received food details
                        JSONArray foodObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_FOOD); // JSON Array

                        // get first product object from JSON Array
                        JSONObject food = foodObj.getJSONObject(0);

                        // Loader image - will be shown before loading image
                        int loader = R.drawable.loader;

                        String image_url = food.getString(TAG_FOODURL);

                        // product with this fid found
                        // Edit Text
                        FoodName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.food_name);
                        FoodPrice = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.food_price);
                        FoodDesc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.food_desc);
                        FoodImg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_food);

                        // display product data in EditText
                        FoodName.setText(food.getString(TAG_FOODNAME));
                        FoodPrice.setText("RM" + food.getString(TAG_FOODPRICE));
                        FoodDesc.setText(food.getString(TAG_FOODDESCRIPTION));

                        // ImageLoader class instance
                        ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());

                        // display image
                        imgLoader.DisplayImage(image_url, loader, FoodImg);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // no food detail found
                        // Launch error message
                        AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(FoodDetailActivity.this);
                        ad.setTitle("Error");
                        ad.setMessage("Food Detail is empty!");
                        ad.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                        {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface, int i)
                            {

                            }
                        });
                        ad.show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) 
    {
        // dismiss the dialog once got all details
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

}

The problem had been solve, i using the ImageLoader retrieve image at server side with url store in database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In here:

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mcchicken); //<<<<
```

you are trying to use context of Activity before `onCreate` call. move `Drawable d` initialization  inside `onCreate` method of Activity after `setContentView` as:

```
Drawable d; //<<< declare d here
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_detail);
    d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mcchicken);  //<< initialize d here
    ....
}
```

**Edit :** : inside `doInBackground` method you are trying to access UI element. instead of updating UI from  doInBackground using `runOnUiThread`. you will need to move all UI related code in `onPostExecute` which call on Ui thread after doInBackground execution complete.

Comment: thanks for pointing out some of my problems, i will try on it..
Can i ask what is the problem about the 
number = Integer.valueOf(quantity); 
i had tried valueOf and parseInt but both will getting error once i press on the plus button..

Comment: @LiangNeo : maybe possible just first trim string before comverting number wrap  `number = Integer.valueOf(quantity);` in try/catch block to catch `NumberFormatException`

Comment: I found the problem, it just need make number become string then it works. i use Number.setText(Integer.toString(number));
thx for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In your code is much messy material. So nicely from the beginning. First is only question.

Why you are putting inside [doInBackground()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground) method [runOnUiThread()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread)? If you want to update your `UI` with some information from task running in background, for this you have **onProgressUpdate()** or `onPostExecute()` method which are synchronized with UI Thread and allow its updates. **doInBackground()** method is directly designated for background processing and you shouldn't broke it.

Then this line:

```
if (food.getString(TAG_FOODNAME) == "McChicken")
```

will always return false because you are comparing references and not values. Always you are comparing strings, you have to use `equals()` method that makes a trick.

And last thing is this:

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mcchicken);
```

You can't call that before `setContentView()` is called. Reason is that main purpose of `setContentView()` is that it creates all instances of UI elements and resources and if you something that requires resources call before this method, always you will get **`NPE`**

Comment: Before i do this i had view a tutorial from [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)
i just new to android within half month, so trying to learn it.. is there any suggest learning material?